# I have a problem. I want to make a flutter-based web application, and I have taken all the required steps, but the web file has not yet appeared

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Image illustrating the steps you have performed

[image: Image illustrating the steps you have performed]

Comment: A couple suggestions. Don't try to add your entire question in the topic. You should try to explain your issue as best as possible in the body of your question. Additionally, images should be used as supporting documents, it's best to show code and sometimes errors in plain text. The image you provided is somewhat difficult to read.

Comment: I want to configure flutter web on vscode

Answer (score 1):

Web file will not appear in this project as you maked it earlier when you are using stable channel. Try to make another project you will see web file .

Comment: Yes, after converting to web-enabled, you'll need another "flutter create ." from the top of your repo to add all the right files.